# Angular JS splice not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, array-splice

I have my data in products.json like this:

```
{
"products":[
{
     "name":"Antricot de vita",
     "calorii":236,
     "proteine":17.4,
     "lipide":18.5,
     "carbohidrati":0,
     "fibre":0
  },
  {
     "name":"Muschi de vita crud",
     "calorii":215,
     "proteine":19,
     "lipide":15,
     "carbohidrati":0,
     "fibre":0
  },
  {
     "name":"Albus de ou",
     "calorii":52,
     "proteine":10.9,
     "lipide":0.2,
     "carbohidrati":0.7,
     "fibre":0
  }
 ]
}
```

So, as you can see I have an array called products which comes with some objects each one having 6 properties. 
I have a table in which every tr has 6 tds with the properties mentioned. When clicked the button on right of each tr I want that tr to be deleted.
The problem occures when I have to delete an element from the table. I have tried a splice function which seems not to work. 
Please help me fix this issue. Thank you so much!
PS: The push function does work!

Below is my code:
app.js

```
    var app = angular.module('Calorii', []);
    app.factory('products', ['$http', function($http) {
      return $http.get('products.json')
        .success(function(data) {
          return data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
          console.log("error");
          return data;
        });
    }]);
    app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'products', function($scope, products) {
      products.success(function(data) {
        $scope.produse = data;
        $scope.predicate = 'name';
        $scope.reverse = false;
        $scope.order = function(predicate) {
          $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
          $scope.predicate = predicate;
        };
        $scope.removeItem = function(item) {
          var index = $scope.produse.products.indexOf(item);
          $scope.produse.products.splice(index, 1);
        };
        $scope.add = function() {
          if (angular.isDefined($scope.name) && $scope.name != '' && $scope.calorii >= 0 &&
            $scope.proteine >= 0 && $scope.lipide >= 0 && $scope.carbohidrati >= 0 &&
            $scope.fibre >= 0) {
            $scope.produse.products.push({
              name: $scope.name,
              calorii: $scope.calorii,
              proteine: $scope.proteine,
              lipide: $scope.lipide,
              carbohidrati: $scope.carbohidrati,
              fibre: $scope.fibre
            });
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.calorii = '';
            $scope.proteine = '';
            $scope.lipide = '';
            $scope.carbohidrati = '';
            $scope.fibre = '';
          } else {
            alert("Unul sau mai multe spatii nu a fost completat");
          }
        };
      });
    }]);
    app.directive('myElement', function() {
      return {
        scope: {
          item: '=myElement'
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<td class="left">{{ item.name }}</td><td>{{ item.calorii }}</td><td class=>{{ item.proteine }}</td><td class>{{ item.lipide }}</td><td class=>{{ item.carbohidrati }}</td><td class=>{{ item.fibre }}</td><td><button ng-click="removeItem(product)"><img src="images/remove.png"/></button></td>'
      };
    });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calorii</title>
    <script src="js/shared/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/shared/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
   <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="Calorii" ng-controller="HomeController">
  <div class="main">
    <div id="header">
      <img src="images/kilocalorii-logo.png">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li id="menulink"><a href="index.html" title="Tabelul de calorii"></a></li>
        <li id="genlink"><a href="#" title="Despre tabelul de calorii"></a></li>
        <li id="searchspot">
        <form id="searchform" class="searchform">
          <input id="s" type="search" ng-model="query">
        </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="rapidfindlabel"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="content">
          <a href="#" class="noSort" ng-click="predicate=''">Doresc tabelul nesortat</a>
          <table class="tabelcalorii"> 
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="left">
            <a href="#" class="sort" ng-click="order('name')">Aliment</a>
            <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <a href="#" class="sort" ng-click="order('calorii')">Calorii</a>
              <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'calorii'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <a href="#" class="sort" ng-click="order('proteine')">Proteine</a>
              <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'proteine'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <a href="#" class="sort" ng-click="order('lipide')">Lipide</a>
              <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'lipide'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <a href="#" class="sort" ng-click="order('carbohidrati')">Carbohidrati</a>
              <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'carbohidrati'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
              <a href="#" class="sort" ng-click="order('fibre')">Fibre</a>
              <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'fibre'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
            </th>
            <th>Scoate din lista</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="product in produse.products | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:query" my-element="product"></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        <p class="more"><strong>Nota:</strong> Toate valorile nutritive sunt calculate pentru o cantitate de 100g.</p>
        <p style="margin-left:5px">Daca nu ai gasit alimentul cautat, adauga-l completand tabelul de mai jos:</p>

        <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" width="100%" class="add_table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="add_name"><b>Aliment:</b></td>
            <td class="add_value"><input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Introdu numele alimentului" style="width: 215px"><br></td>
            <td><span class="sugestie">exemplu: <b>Pate de porc cu verdeturi Bucegi</b></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="add_name" valign="top"><b>Calorii:</b></td>
            <td class="add_value"><input type="number" ng-model="calorii" placeholder="Introdu numarul de calorii" style="width: 215px"><br></td>
            <td><span class="sugestie">completarea numarului de calorii este obligatorie</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="add_name" valign="top"><b>Proteine:</b></td>
            <td class="add_value"><input type="number" ng-model="proteine" placeholder="Introdu numarul de proteine" style="width: 215px"><br></td>
            <td><span class="sugestie">completarea numarului de proteine este obligatorie</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="add_name" valign="top"><b>Lipide:</b></td>
            <td class="add_value"><input type="number" ng-model="lipide" placeholder="Introdu numarul de lipide" style="width: 215px"><br></td>
            <td><span class="sugestie">completarea numarului de lipide este obligatorie</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="add_name" valign="top"><b>Carbohidrati:</b></td>
            <td class="add_value"><input type="number" ng-model="carbohidrati" placeholder="Introdu numarul de carbohidrati" style="width: 215px"><br></td>
            <td><span class="sugestie">completarea numarului de carbohidrati este obligatorie</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="add_name" valign="top"><b>Fibre:</b></td>
            <td class="add_value"><input type="number" ng-model="fibre" placeholder="Introdu numarul de fibre" style="width: 215px"><br></td>
            <td><span class="sugestie">completarea numarului de fibre este obligatorie</span></td>
          </tr>
              <button class="submit" ng-click="add()">ADAUGA</button>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>

     <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>


 </body>
</html>
```

I know there is plenty of code above, but if you don't mind I would appreciate if you could explain shortly how to call splice function on my json products. Thanks again!

Comment: You should really need to isolate issues with fewer code if you want answers here...

Comment: Instead of relying in the indexOf function to get the item index, you should pass it from the front. ng-click="removeItem($index)" and then in your controller use that param as index to splice

Comment: If you put a `alert` or `console.log` in your `function removeItem` it works? I think you have a problem in your directive, that doesn't find your controller scope.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte it seems like not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

indexOf sometimes fails to find the index of an object in an array. Either you use lodash or underscore to do so, or change your approach:

```
<td><a ng-click="removeItem($index)">Remove</a></td>
```

Ctrl

```
$scope.removeItem = function(index) {
   $scope.produse.products.splice(index, 1);
}
```

$index as available to you when using ng-repeat in angular.

Comment: Make sure you enter that function. Add a console.log inside or some shit to make sure it's calling the right function

Comment: Nothing is displayed although I added console.log into that function

Comment: Can you put together some plnkr or codepen so we can check?

Comment: Here you go. You have to call the function with $parent.removeItem($index). https://plnkr.co/edit/CLWlOp4M7uWhAtAM6tBs?p=preview

Comment: I see... Now as I was trying to check it I noticed different items are being removed when clicked on 'Remove' instead of the one selected(sometimes it also happens to be the right one). How come?

Comment: Well, that's cause of the way you did it. You are passing the product as a param to your directive, thus losing the $index. Either you pass also the index so you can use it, or you put the ng-repeat inside the directive and call the directive only once, passing the array of objects instead of a single object. I think that directive there makes no sense; are you using that directive somewhere else in your application?

Comment: Thank you very much! Well, instead of writing six lines of code in index.html I prefer to use a directive to do it(that's what codecademy taught me :))) )

Comment: Well, in that case call the directive and pass the whole object, and do the ng-repeat inside the directive. That way you won't lose the $index. ^^

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with myElement directive.

```
ng-click="removeItem(product)"
```

it should be

```
ng-click="removeItem(item)".
```

Comment: The problem is directive isolated scope. So you need to change the directive not to use isolated scope. This is the reason why your function is never called

Comment: How can I change it? I mean, what needs to be modified?

Comment: Change template directive as: template: '<td class="left">{{ item.name }}</td><td>{{ item.calorii }}</td><td class=>{{ item.proteine }}</td><td class>{{ item.lipide }}</td><td class=>{{ item.carbohidrati }}</td><td class=>{{ item.fibre }}</td><td><button ng-click="$parent.removeItem(item)">Remove</button></td>'

Comment: Works now. Thank you very much!